# Trouble finding certain Java OpenJDK downloads

Tags: java, download, archive

- Where on the internet do I go to download the Java OpenJDK standalone **runtimes** that correspond these versions, {https://jdk.java.net/archive/, along with this latest version,
  https://jdk.java.net/19/ } ?
- Where on the internet do I go to download all files required to build these same OpenJDK versions, using source code and resource files? Both for the JDK and the JRE, for each version starting from 9 and up to 19, the present version at the time of this post?

Comment: OpenJDK(.org) itself doesn't publish binary releases for endusers, only sources. To find an OpenJDK based source / binary match you need to check each vendor how they build their releases and what sources they use. For example some backport patches (e.g. [amazon](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8)) so it's not necessarily the plain OpenJDK state. Open source licenses may not require you to share the exact toolchain / commands used to build the binary so that part can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Most JDK products are built largely, if not entirely, from source code published at the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project. See [GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/).

Technically, you could compile that source code yourself. But the codebase is large and complicated. Producing a binary would be quite an effort. And doing so is quite unnecessary as several vendors provide JDK binaries and/or installers.

These JDK vendors include [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk), IBM, [Red Hat](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download), [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc), [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/), Oracle, [SAP](https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/), [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/), [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk), and more. Some of these vendors provide a JRE in addition to a JDK. Some vendors offer paid support plans.

As for versions:

- Only versions 8, 11, and 17 are long-term support versions.
- Version 19 is the current version.

All other versions have a lifespan of only several months. So you are not likely to see those interstitial versions maintained. Only those four mentioned versions are currently maintained.

See the white paper, [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the openJDK source code its available on GitHub https://github.com/openjdk/jdk with instructions on how to build it https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/doc/building.md